# Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch CTH-470 3+ finger gestures

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet, gestures

I love my ***CTH-470*** and I'm glad it's without having to spend hours in the Terminal to get it working since I believe 12.10 (which I'm running now). But in the [manual](http://www.wacom.com/~/media/Files/Manuals/Bamboo%202011%20Users%20Manual.pdf) it states that you can swipe with three or even four fingers.

However, I can't seem to find how to '*activate*' this on Ubuntu.

- Is this even possible?
- If yes, how?
- And if no, are there any plans to support this in the future?

Extra information:

```
$ xsetwacom --list devices
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus    id: 10  type: STYLUS    
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch  id: 11  type: TOUCH     
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser    id: 13  type: ERASER    
Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger pad    id: 14  type: PAD
```

Comment: I'm using a Wacom Bamboo Pen & Touch CTH-460/K on Ubuntu 12.04. This also supports three and four finger touch (that's what the /K is for, apparently; under Windows I've tested this to be the case). Under Ubuntu, it does no more than 2 fingers. I see the following when running "dmesg | grep Wacom": input: Wacom BambooPT 2FG 4x5 Finger -- looks like the driver picks it up as a 2-finger touch (2FG) device. What does it say in your dmesg?

Comment: @CharlBotha It says 'input: Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.1/input/input5', though I don't think it would be physically possible one could use 16 fingers, so are you sure it expresses the amount of fingers it should/could support? By the way, it shows the same line twice, except for 'Finger', which is 'Pen' on the other line.

Comment: 12.10 hasn't been supported for a while now, I recommend you install either 15.04 or 14.04 LTS, and continue from there.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and the same problem still exists. You can use it as a tablet, and you can use it to point, click and two-finger-scroll. No other gestures are supported by default. I'm also interested in solutions to this.

Comment: have you tried manually adding it via `xinput` ?

Comment: I haven't, no @AliRezaMosajjal. Will try, but at the moment I don't have access to my system with Ubuntu (which is now 14.04 or 14.10 and it doesn't work out of the box there either). Thanks for the suggestion, will keep you updated!

Comment: @AliRezaMosajjal could you explain what you mean by adding it manually?  I can do things like `xinput set-prop "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch" --type=float "Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration" 2.150000` already, so I'm assuming it's already using xinput.

Comment: @verpfeilt The answer by Martin Owens works as far as I know. Please see my comment for the downsides of touchegg.

Comment: @FMJansen yes that's what I meant. if it's already using `xinput` you can list all the functionality of it and change whatever you want. take a look at [this post](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input) for more info

Comment: @verpfeilt Your edit was inconsistent with the other information in the question (which was about a Bamboo, not an Intuos), so I changed it to my own output.

Comment: Ah sorry I confused this.

Answer (score 1):

According to an older post on the forum[1], it's better to use Ubuntu's native touch support and I will condense the information that fixed this issue:

Update or make sure you're using version `0.20.0` or above for `xf86-input-wacom` driver package:

```
xsetwacom -V
```

Install touchegg package:

```
sudo apt-get install touchegg
```

Turn `OFF` wacom's own touch guesture support so ubuntu's touchegg can take guesture control:

```
xsetwacom set "Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch" Gesture off
```

You may need to replace the name above in quotes with the name of your finger *pen* device name which you can find doing `xsetwacom --list devices`

Use the touchegg configuration tool or edit the touchegg configuration file to adjust timeouts as needed.

You should now have working multi-touch support.

[1] http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2125990.html

Comment: Thanks for posting this. Important to note: I'm sirolf10 at the ubuntuforums. So yes, this did work, but not that great. "When you release your fingers after scrolling it sometimes scrolls back and you can't right-click and move your cursor directly afterwards anymore, you have to lift your finger first." This led me to stop using touchegg. It did work for the 3+ finger gestures, though. My excuses for not mentioning this earlier myself, should have done that.

Comment: That sounds very much like a half a dozen bugs in touchegg; it should be fixed rather than using a driver which isn't integrated into the system in the same way.

Comment: As soon as I use `xsetwacom set "Wacom Intuos PT S Touch touch" Gesture off` I can't even move the cursor. I also tried the "Pad" device, but nothing changed. I used the touchegg gui for configuration and I could not get it running. (Ubuntu 15.04, xsetwacom 0.25.0)